# Update Android Studio 2.2 to 2.2.1 failed and studio64.exe file is missing

Tags: android, android-studio

Today when I opened Android Studio, I found that 2.2.1 was available, so I updated. But unfortunately an error occurred, something conflicts. And in the end, the file is missing and I couldn't open Android Studio again. Of course, I  can download it again, but it's too troublesome. So anyone faced this issue?

Comment: You have to download it again, it will be the best option for you so that you will have a clean system.

Comment: @JerryHanks  Yes, you are right. It's easy to install again, and fortunately my projects are still on it !  And  I dont't have to worry about such thing any more lol :)